# Doctrine2 entity and Zf2 JsonModel()

Tags: doctrine-orm, iterator, zend-framework2, traversal

I see a few ways to give `Zend\View\Model\ViewModel::setVariables` an array:

- Implement in entity toArray() and make JsonModel($entity->toArray())
- Use `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject` and `$hydrator->extract($entity);`
- Implement Iterator for entity and extends from it

And the question is, how can i implement iterator for Doctrine2 entity, and is it a good idea or maybe someone know a better way?

Answer (score -2):

Generally, iterating an entity is a bad idea.

If you want to pass your entity to a view template, you can do the following:

```
<?php
// IndexController.php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

  // The "index" action
  public function indexAction() { 

    // Create your entity here
    $entity = ...

    // Pass it to view template for rendering
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'entity' => $entity
    ));
  }  
}
```

Then, in your view template, you will be able to access the entity in the following way:

```
<?php echo $this->entity->getId(); ?>
```

Comment: I'm talking about JsonModel(), and json response from the RestfulController

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.jsonserializable.php тоже не подходит, так как, вьюха принимает или массив или http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.traversable.php

Comment: downvoted because this does not answer the question.